# Kronos JBOSS application monitoring

Tags: java, jboss, prometheus, kronos-workforce-central, kronos-workforce-ready-suite

I want to monitor the Kronos application using JMX exporter. We are very new to this application and want to set up monitoring for the same using Prometheus. We have followed the below steps as of now and not sure about the .jar file location. Can someone please help with the steps.

Env: Running on Windows Machine

> Downloaded jmx exporter
> created the xml and yml file.

Getting issue while trying to start JMX using jar file. We are not aware of the jar file location that needs to give in place of myapp.jar

java -javaagent:./jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.11.0.jar=8181:config.yaml -jar myapp.jar

Thanks & Regards,
Srikanta